# How to choose $k$ of $n$ urns to maximize the number of colors of balls?

Tags: expectation-maximization, conditional-expectation

Say we have $N$ urns, each containing many colored balls, but we only know the probability $p_{ci}$ that urn $i$ contains at least one ball of color $c$ (expressible as a $c$-vector ${\bf p}_i$).  Suppose we wish to pick $K<N$ urns with the goal of maximizing the number of different colors contained in those $K$ urns.  How do we decide which urns to pick?

I've been utilizing something akin to principal component analysis, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach.  The idea is to use an iterative approach with a color weight vector ${\bf w}(s)$, where $w_c(s)$ indicates the probability we have not yet seen color $c$ at iteration $s$, with initial condition $w_c(0) = 1$ for all $c$.

We pick one urn on each iteration $s$ such that it maximizes the number of colors we haven't seen before, by maximizing the value ${\bf w}(s) \cdot {\bf  p}_i$ over $i$.  If $j(s)$ denotes the urn chosen on iteration $s$, we then choose ${\bf w}(s+1)$ s.t. $w_c(s+1) = w_c(s) * (1-p_{cj(s)})$.  Each urn can only be chosen once, so max(${\bf w}(s) \cdot {\bf  p}_i$) is really over $i$-not-yet-chosen-at-iteration-$s$.

The problem has two variants -- with and without peeking (*i.e.*, at iteration $s$, can you look in the urns you've picked so far to help pick $j(s+1)$ ).

The actual real-world problem this comes from is:  I'm a birdwatcher with limited time.  I can only go birding on $K<52$ weekends of the year.  I know the probability $p_{ci}$ of seeing bird species $c$ on weekend $i$ (in general, $p_{ci} \ne p_{cj}$ due to migration, seasonal food availability, etc.).  If I plan at the beginning of the year which weekends to go birding, how do I maximize the number of species I see in one year?

Which raises a third variant of the problem:  after weekend $i$, I know which species I've seen; this might change my plans for the remaining trips.  This is akin to "peeking", but I'm not peeking at the urns in the same order.  In this case, one picks all $K$ urns, but then is allowed to peek in the lowest-indexed urn, and possibly change the selection of the remaining $K-1$ urns based on the first urn's contents.

Comment: Regarding the real (birdwatching) problem, how did you get the $p_{ci}$s? If you estimated them from data, you can likely use that data to get a more direct solution to the problem of choosing which weekends to birdwatch on. Describing the dataset [in detail](http://arfer.net/w/statqgl) could be helpful.

Comment: This problem sounds somewhat related to [Best arm identification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/sebubeck/COLT10_ABM.pdf)

Comment: @Kodiologist, the $p_{ci}$ values come from ebird.org data.  Observers submit checklists of birds seen at one location on a given date.  The checklists for a region (*e.g.* the state of NJ) are compiled into a spreadsheet giving $p_{ci}$ as the percent of checklists for week $i$ (over all years) containing species $c$.

Comment: The third variant is easier to solve and more realistic.  All variants, however, lack essential information: because the outcome is random, you cannot guarantee maximization of the number of species.  You can only anticipate some probability distribution of the number of species.  Two probability distributions cannot be compared to determine which is "better" until you supply a "loss function" that lets us quantify which distribution is better.  In brief, you need to *quantify* in each case how much it's worth to you to see just $1, 2, \ldots, \approx 600$ species in a year.

Comment: @whuber, i agree that the outcome of a given solution is a PDF.  What i want to do is maximize the expectation value of the PDF.  For now, i assume a constant cost function within a given constraint, e.g. K=12 or some such.  But i agree a nontrivial cost function could further inform the solution.